# How to initialize database with certain values activeandroid

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I'm using ActiveAndroid as an ORM.
I want to initialize my database tables with certain values.Only one time,I dont want the content to be duplicated.

or is there a solution to execute a sql script at installation time.

I searched in the documentation but I didnt found it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check your table, and if it was empty, then insert your data into it. you can have several tables, and should do the same for each one

```
List <Category> categories = new Select()
        .from(Category.class)
        .where("your where clause here")    // your where clause
        .execute();

if (categories != null && categories.size() > 0 ) {
      // data is inserted before 
} else {
      Category newCategory = new Category("category");
      newCategory.save();
} 

List <Item> items = new Select()
        .from(Item.class)
        .where("your where clause")
        .execute();

if (items != null && items.size() > 0 ) {
      // data is inserted before 
} else {
      Item item = new Item("item");
      item.save();
}
```

now new data will insert into table only when they're not exist in your table and won't duplicate.

and in other solution you might use pre-populated database and use that in your application.

Comment: so, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: What I mean is: for example: Categories cat1 = new Categories("Food");
cat1.save();
Item item1  = new Item("lunch");
item1.setCategory(cat1);
item1.save();

Comment: the problem here is at every execution, the content well be duplicated;
I want to void that by adding them automatically to Database

Comment: check my answer. I've explained more. data won't be duplicated because you are checking if there isn't any data in your table, you insert them and if there was some data, you won't insert anything.

Comment: so I need to add a method to compare the name of each object and compare it with the newest one,if it is already existed, I'm !save,if not then save(),thanks alot.

Comment: Also the second solution is great,but I need to check  about it,

Comment: your welcome! don't forget to read [documentation](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki) it'll help you more! ;)